# Kafka10 auto.commit.interval.ms property

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api

I have set auto commit interval to 5 secs. What if the poll() method takes 10 secs to complete processing.

Will it still commit at every 5 secs or waits until the next poll()?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It cannot be guaranteed to commit every 5 seconds even if you set `auto.commit.interval.ms` to 5 seconds. Technically, I agree with your statement of `waits until the next poll`.

Handling offset commit will be checked first in a single `poll` round. In fact, polling coordinator events is the very beginning thing that `KafkaConsumer#poll` does, which including ensuring coordinator's aliveness, consumer's successful joining group and also taking care of auto-commit-offset things. During this check, coordinator decides whether it should commit offsets. And it is executed from within a same thread where `poll` is called, so a precise 5-second interval cannot be achieved and until the next poll coordinator does not handle those things.